# Swift slower than Flutter for select sort algorithm

Tags: swift, algorithm, flutter, performance

I implemented select sort in Flutter and in SwiftUI. I made the implementations as similar as possible.

Swift:

```swift
func selectSort(list: inout [Double]) -> [Double] {
    for i in 0..<list.count {
        var minElPos = i;
        for j in (minElPos + 1)..<list.count {
            if list[j] < list[minElPos] {
                minElPos = j;
            }
        }
        // swap
        let temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[minElPos];
        list[minElPos] = temp;
    }
    return list;
}

// Measuring time

func generateRandomList(size: Int) -> [Double] {
    var res = Array<Double>(repeating: 0.0, count: size)
    for i in 0..<size {
        res[i] = Double.random(in: 0...1)
    }
    return res;
}

var arrayToTest: [Double] = generateRandomList(size: 8000);
let startingPoint = Date()
selectSort(list: &arrayToTest);
let time = startingPoint.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1;
```

Flutter:

```dart
class SelectSort {
  static List<double> call(List<double> list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
      int minElPos = i;
      for(int j = minElPos + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
        if(list[j] < list[minElPos]) {
          minElPos = j;
        }
      }
      // swap
      double temp = list[i];
      list[i] = list[minElPos];
      list[minElPos] = temp;
    }
    return list;
  }
}
// Measuring time

class Utils {
  static List<double> generateRandomList(int nbOfElements) {
    var random = new Random();
    List<double> res = List(nbOfElements);
    for (var i = 0; i < nbOfElements; i++) {
      res[i] = random.nextDouble();
    }
    return res;
  }
}

List<double> arrayToTest = Utils.generateRandomList(8000);
final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
SelectSort.call(arrayToTest);
stopwatch.stop();
int time = stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds;
```

I measured the execution time for an array of random numbers. The array size is 8000. Flutter needs 0.053s and SwiftUI needs 0.141s. Does anyone have a clue why flutter as a hybrid framework has better performance than a native solution?

Both apps were run in release mode on a physical device.

Comment: Please show the code you used to measure both code snippets. We need to be able to reproduce your results.

Comment: @Sweeper I added the code responsible for time measuring. Do you want me to post the whole code of the application?

Comment: Your Flutter variant is operating in-place (and also happens to return the result, but it's a reference to the same in-place mutated array as was given as an argument), whereas your Swift variant makes a copy and operates on that.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for the comment. I've tried several versions. The result is the same if I operate in place for both frameworks - the sorting time dominates the copying time. I've updated the code so both versions are "in place" now.

Comment: @Alexander True, but `inout` could be optimised to a pass by reference, couldn’t it?

Comment: @Sweeper The argument passing to `inout` isn't what's doing the copying, it's the creation of a new local variable `list` which is a second reference to the same underlying array. The first mutation to `list` would trigger a CoW copy

Comment: @K.Drab Perhaps  Shot in the dark: what you might be seeing is overhead of the runtime machinery that checks for exclusive memory access violations. Try using `list.swapAt(i, minElPos)` instead of the hand rolled 3-line-swap. Try disabling "Exclusive Access to Memory" in the build settings of your project.

Comment: @Alexander thank you for your comment. I didn't know about the Exclusive Access in Swift so I think I've learnt something :). I tried both things you mentioned but they didn't improve the performance. Profiler shows that 99% of the time is "Array.subscript.getter
". It makes sense because there is O(n^2) of reading elements and only O(n) of writing. I think I'll just accept that in this case, Swift is slower.

Comment: Try the unsafe optimization flag, i forget what it’s called. It’ll remove the bounds checks done on every access, perhaps that’s what’s slowing things down. Though it would surprise me if Swift was actually slower in this regard. It’s usual performance issues relate to ARC retain/release traffic. Something like this should be incredibly fast.

Comment: Could you check to see if flutter is doing any auto-vectorization on this code?

Comment: @Alexander Compiled with options: Disable safety checks = "Yes"; Exclusive Access to Memory = "Compile-time only"; Optimization level = "Optimize for Speed". The result is the same. Regarding auto-vectorization. Is there any other option to check it than decompiling the binary?